# Stream from Icecast interputed after few seconds

Tags: stream, icecast

I have a stream based on Icecast server. It works on most of devices and browsers, but there is an issue for example on android mobile chrome - I can run stream, but it lasts 2 few seconds and it stops. User reports as well the on other browser and devices.

This is player info from mobile, where issue occures:

```
{
  "properties": {},
  "messages": [
    {
      "level": "info",
      "message": "FFmpegDemuxer: created audio stream, config codec: mp3, profile: unknown, bytes_per_channel: 2, channel_layout: STEREO, channels: 2, samples_per_second: 44100, sample_format: Signed 16-bit planar, bytes_per_frame: 4, seek_preroll: 0us, codec_delay: 0, has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, discard decoder delay: true, target_output_channel_layout: NONE, target_output_sample_format: Unknown sample format, has aac extra data: false"
    },
    {
      "level": "info",
      "message": "Selected FFmpegAudioDecoder for audio decoding, config: codec: mp3, profile: unknown, bytes_per_channel: 2, channel_layout: STEREO, channels: 2, samples_per_second: 44100, sample_format: Signed 16-bit planar, bytes_per_frame: 4, seek_preroll: 0us, codec_delay: 0, has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, discard decoder delay: true, target_output_channel_layout: STEREO, target_output_sample_format: Unknown sample format, has aac extra data: false"
    },
    {
      "level": "info",
      "message": "Effective playback rate changed from 0 to 1"
    },
    {
      "level": "debug",
      "message": "FFmpegDemuxer: av_read_frame(): End of file"
    }
  ],
  "events": [
    {
      "timestamp": 428923.310863,
      "value": {
        "created": "2022-06-07 11:42:54.362 UTC"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.000",
      "event": "kMediaLogCreated"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428923.311442,
      "value": {
        "origin_url": "https://stream.xxxx.xxx:8443/"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.001",
      "event": "kWebMediaPlayerCreated"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428923.311785,
      "value": {
        "url": "https://stream.xxxx.xxx:8443/xxxxxxx.mp3?16545998452"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.001",
      "event": "kLoad"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428923.405597,
      "value": {
        "pipeline_state": "kStarting"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.095",
      "event": "kPipelineStateChange"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428923.432143,
      "value": {
        "pipeline_state": "kPlaying"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.121",
      "event": "kPipelineStateChange"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428923.426763,
      "value": {
        "duration": 2.718765
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.116",
      "event": "kDurationChanged"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428923.439653,
      "value": {
        "pipeline_buffering_state": {
          "for_suspended_start": false,
          "state": "BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH"
        }
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.129",
      "event": "kBufferingStateChanged"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428926.138386,
      "value": {},
      "displayTimestamp": "2.828",
      "event": "kPlay"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428929.103,
      "value": {},
      "displayTimestamp": "5.792",
      "event": "kEnded"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 428929.105783,
      "value": {},
      "displayTimestamp": "5.795",
      "event": "kPause"
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

This player info from desktop, where is no issue:

```
{
  "properties": {},
  "messages": [
    {
      "level": "info",
      "message": "FFmpegDemuxer: created audio stream, config codec: mp3, profile: unknown, bytes_per_channel: 2, channel_layout: STEREO, channels: 2, samples_per_second: 44100, sample_format: Signed 16-bit planar, bytes_per_frame: 4, seek_preroll: 0us, codec_delay: 0, has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, discard decoder delay: true, target_output_channel_layout: NONE, target_output_sample_format: Unknown sample format, has aac extra data: false"
    },
    {
      "level": "info",
      "message": "Selected FFmpegAudioDecoder for audio decoding, config: codec: mp3, profile: unknown, bytes_per_channel: 2, channel_layout: STEREO, channels: 2, samples_per_second: 44100, sample_format: Signed 16-bit planar, bytes_per_frame: 4, seek_preroll: 0us, codec_delay: 0, has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, discard decoder delay: true, target_output_channel_layout: STEREO, target_output_sample_format: Unknown sample format, has aac extra data: false"
    },
    {
      "level": "info",
      "message": "Effective playback rate changed from 0 to 1"
    }
  ],
  "events": [
    {
      "timestamp": 45942.954686,
      "value": {
        "created": "2022-06-07 11:48:19.885 UTC"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.000",
      "event": "kMediaLogCreated"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 45942.954777,
      "value": {
        "origin_url": "https://stream.xxxx.xxx:8443/"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.000",
      "event": "kWebMediaPlayerCreated"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 45942.954829,
      "value": {
        "url": "https://stream.xxxx.xxx:8443/xxxx.mp3"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.000",
      "event": "kLoad"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 45943.121403,
      "value": {
        "pipeline_state": "kStarting"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "0.167",
      "event": "kPipelineStateChange"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 45946.605256,
      "value": {
        "duration": "unknown"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "3.651",
      "event": "kDurationChanged"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 45946.609078,
      "value": {
        "pipeline_state": "kPlaying"
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "3.654",
      "event": "kPipelineStateChange"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 45946.609662,
      "value": {
        "pipeline_buffering_state": {
          "for_suspended_start": false,
          "state": "BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH"
        }
      },
      "displayTimestamp": "3.655",
      "event": "kBufferingStateChanged"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 45949.870751,
      "value": {},
      "displayTimestamp": "6.916",
      "event": "kPlay"
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

I have noticed that on mobile duration is provided, but I don't know why.

This is fragment icecast.xml config, which doesn't contain vulnerable data:

```
    <http-headers>
        <header name="Cache-control" value="no-cache" />
    </http-headers>

    <limits>
        <clients>500</clients>
        <sources>10</sources>
        <threadpool>5</threadpool>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>60</source-timeout>
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>
```

Of course required behaviour is no interrupting

Comment: Does Icecast log anything particular which corresponds to the event when client experiences this interruption?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, sorry the late replay. I through logs and nothing particular is visible in them. In meantime I found, that could be because too high bitrate. Current it is 139kbps, then I test it with lower bitrate 80kbps - no progress. I can try it with lower, but it would sound very bad. :(

Comment: No, it shouldn't depend on bitrate or require bitrate so low. I streamed even *video* streams through Icecast without interruptions, obviously the bitrate was higher. There is something different.